# Bootstrap-sprockets.js not loading in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I am having trouble loading my bootstrap-sprockets.js file in my Rails app. Currently, here is my Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.3.4'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'rails-controller-testing'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

And my application.js file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

[And this is what I have on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riiOh.png)

The end problem of all of this is that my mobile navigation isn't working. Here is the _navigation.html.erb file (just in case):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-primary navbar-fixed-top" id="sectionsNav">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-primary">                   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_path %>">List Overflow<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-primary">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

              <% if user_signed_in? %>
                          <li>
                           <%= link_to listings_path do %>
                             <i class="material-icons">reorder</i> Listings
                           <% end %>
                          </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="material-icons">add</i> Actions
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        <div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-with-icons">
                <li><%= link_to "New Listing", new_listing_path %></li>
                <% if current_user.admin? %>
                  <li><%= link_to "New Category", new_category_path %></li>
                <% end %>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
            <% end %>

            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">person</i><%= "(Admin)" if current_user.admin? %> <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "View profile", user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path, class: "btn btn-info btn-raised btn-round" %></li>
            <% end %>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

If you want to see a live version, you can go to listoverflow.herokuapp.com

I previously thought it was an issue with jQuery loading (you can see that post here), but it is actually loading fine as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hylov.png).

**Edit:** It is worth noting that I am using the Material Kit Pro template from creative-tim.com. Not sure if something with that is messing up how the asset-pipeline is loading documents. Here is the way I am importing my SCSS:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "devise_bootstrap_views";
@import "sass2/material-kit.scss";
@import "demo"; # from Material Kit
@import "vertical-nav"; # from Material Kit
@import "listings"; # Custom by me
@import "custom"; # Custom by me
```

Comment: Did you restart your server and did you @import the bootstrap files?

Comment: Yes, and I imported bootstrap-sprockets before bootstrap. Also, if you mean exiting rails s and then restarting it again, then yes I have restarted my server.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It is probably worth mentioning that I am using the custom Material Kit gem from creative-tim.com. I should have mentioned this earlier. I will go back and add more to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually loading bootstrap-sprockets twice, which was causing the javascript to undo itself (for example, the mobile navbar was supposed to fold back on going to another page, but instead folded in and then undid it - since the JS was running twice).

**Moral**: Check to make sure your files are in order.